# Forcing a ItemsControl panel to repaint

Tags: wpf, repaint, wrappanel

Alright, I have a ListBox that holds container controls.  Each container control contains 1-X widgets and these widgets are laid out in a completely custom WrapPanel and it's working great.  The size of the widgets is determined/updated from 2 factors:

1. The size of the parent listbox (updated if changed)
2. A view scale SliderBar (25%, 50%, 100%) - like a zoom button

If the listbox size is changed, the custom panel repaints and sizes of widgets are adjusted accordingly in my code.  Working perfect.

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="lstGroups" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TopLevelGroups}" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SizeChanged="ListBox_SizeChanged" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             SelectionMode="Extended"
                    Style="{ StaticResource ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Horizontal }"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Margin="5">View Scale:</Label>
        <Slider Name="sldView" Minimum="25" Maximum="100" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Ticks="25,50,100" Width="125" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=StopCommand}" Content="Stop" Height="30" Width="60" Margin="1" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanStop}" x:Name="btnStop" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=RunCommand}" Content="Run" Height="30" Width="60"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanRun}" x:Name="btnRun" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

--Widget--

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding Path=EditCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsMonitorStopped}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsMonitorStopped}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <Image Source="" Margin="2" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entities}" Name="icEntities" >
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AppleViewModel}">
                <ct:AppleTile Height="{Binding Path=AppleHeight}" Width="{Binding Path=AppleWidth}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrangeViewModel}">
                <ct:OrangeTile Height="{Binding Path=OrangeHeight}" Width="{Binding Path=OrangeWidth}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GrapeViewModel}">
                <ct:GrapeTile Height="{Binding Path=GrapeHeight}" Width="{Binding Path=GrapeWidth}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- Custom Wrap panel -->
                <co:MonitorPanel x:Name="mpMain"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

If the user moves the Slider bar for zoom in/zoom out - I need to be able to force the custom panels to re-render with the newly calculated widget sizes.

```
private void ListBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Works perfect
    this.ResetViewScale(e.NewSize);
}
```

...here comes trouble:

```
 private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        ...code here
        this.ResetViewScale(new Size(this.myListBox.ActualWidth, this.myListBox.ActualHeight));
        //How can I repaint my list/panel?
    }

private void ResetViewScale(Size e)
    {
        Size newSize = new Size(e.Height / 2, e.Height / 2);

        switch (App.ApplicationViewScale)
        {
            case ViewScale.Full:
                Size full = new Size(newSize.Height, newSize.Height);
                App.TileSize = new Size(full.Height, full.Width);
                break;
            case ViewScale.Half:
                Size half = new Size(newSize.Height / 2, newSize.Height / 2);
                App.TileSize = new Size(half.Height, half.Width);
                break;
            case ViewScale.Quarter:
                Size quarter = new Size(newSize.Height / 4, newSize.Height / 4);
                App.TileSize = new Size(quarter.Height, quarter.Width);
                break;
            default:
                Size defaultToFull = new Size(newSize.Height, newSize.Height);
                App.TileSize = new Size(defaultToFull.Height, defaultToFull.Width);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I tried using all the Invalidate methods but nothing seems to be working.  Sorta stuck...

Comment: Try an InvalidateMeasure, before an InvalidateVisual

Comment: Can you show what you are doing in the ResetViewScale, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response but all I am doing is setting my widget size.  Its important to note that this code fires in both events above, except that the ListBox repaints on SizeChanged and of course does not repaint on my slider value changed:

Comment: I assume that the custom Widgets sizes are bound to App.TileSize? Can you show the DependencyProperty (or Properties) on the CustomWidgets that effect their size?

Comment: Each widget's Height and Width are determined by App.TileSize in each widget types ViewModel:

public double WidgetXHeight
        {
            get
            {
                return App.TileSize.Height;
            }
        }

        public double WidgetXWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return App.TileSize.Width * 2;
            }
        }

Comment: I guess the point is that ResetViewScale(Size e) is called in both scenarios so App.TileSize is updated in both cases.  The issue is that the the ListBox/panel doesn't repaint unless it itself is resized.

Comment: How about calling InvalidateMeasure/InvalidateVisual on the parent container of the ListBox to cause a measure/layout pass.

Comment: Could you show us the XAML tree....as you mention you have some panels.

Comment: I've provided the parent xaml and the ListBox widget xaml as well.  I tried InvalidateMeasure/Visual on both the listBox and the parent and neither works.